# Implement publish/subscribe with Boost Beast

Tags: c++, boost-beast, beast-websockets

I have a Websocket server based on Boost Beast and I want to implement a publish / subscribe pattern. My current code base is based on the advanced/flex example.

Is there a recipe / pattern on how to implement a pub/sub channel with Beast?

Specifically, I wonder what's the correct way to lookup a session and send data initiated by the server (e.g. the server generated event data and wants to publish this data to subscribers).

Comment: Have a look at the code here: https://github.com/vinniefalco/BeastLounge/ Feel free to open issues if you have questions about specific code, I will answer them.